# Einstein Email Recommendation | Same recommendation for a user from email sent multiple times

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein, einstein-recommendations

We have configured Einstein email recommendations for users who are part of a journey in marketing cloud. Any user who makes a purchase on the website becomes eligible to enter this journey and receives an email containing recommendations. After a gap of few days, if user makes a purchase again, they become eligible to enter this journey and receives the email.

The issue we saw with one of the users is that he has received more than 5 emails from this journey at different times with exact same set of 6 recommendations every single time.

There is one caveat to this though. This user made his last purchase on the website back in February 2022. And after that, he has made couple of purchases on the stores. Now, since we receive store purchase data as well and our logic for journey audience uses store customers+ website customers+ app customers, this user has been a part of the journey multiple times.

The scenario configured is- Bought Bought Last Purchase, View Bought Last Purchase, New Releases

My understanding is that even though this user is not making purchases on the website now, the above configured scenario would still update the recommendations since other users have been buying the products that this user bought in February on the website.
Is my understanding correct?

Also, is there a way to not recommend same products that have been recommended to a user before?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: There is no guarantee the boughtbought last purchase has changed items since last email

Comment: @EazyE we checked the IGO purchase data extensions and could see that the items purchased last by the user has been purchased by many users since then. If not all, I think at least one recommendation out of the 6 should change due to this.

Comment: You can go review the list for that item in reporting >> admin content >> list

Comment: Hi @EazyE.. is there a way to not recommend same products that have been recommended to a user before?

Comment: there is not a way